# error CS0433: The type 'IWindowsIAP' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Purchasing.WinRTCore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.purchasing@4.1.5\Runtime\WinRTStub\Factory.cs(15,23): error CS0433: The type 'IWindowsIAP' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Purchasing.WinRTCore, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'winrt, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Any resolution?